# React Native - Error reading JSON Data properly (Type Error: undefined is not an object)

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

currently, I'm working on a school project where we have to program an app. We need to get the latitude and Longitude from an address. I found the Google API and the HERE API, but for the Google API, you need to give credit card information so we won't use that.

I already looked around, but I couldn't find anything that could help me in my situation.

My problem is to read the data from the responseJson. I get this error.

> [Tue Jan 05 2021 17:16:18.172]  LOG      TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'responseJson[0].ResponseView')::: Error Message

This is the code snippet that gets called

```js
function setLocation(plz, town, street, hnr) {

    fetch('https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey={API-KEY}&searchtext=' + plz + '+' + town + '+' + street + '+' + hnr, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson[0].ResponseView.Result.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error + "::: Error Message");
        });
}
```

This is the data that we get as a result when we call the link

```js
{
    "Response": {
        "MetaInfo": {
            "Timestamp": "2021-01-05T16:10:19.142+0000"
        },
        "View": [
            {
                "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
                "ViewId": 0,
                "Result": [
                    {
                        "Relevance": 0.97,
                        "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
                        "MatchQuality": {
                            "City": 0.89,
                            "Street": [
                                1.0
                            ],
                            "HouseNumber": 1.0,
                            "PostalCode": 1.0
                        },
                        "MatchType": "pointAddress",
                        "Location": {
                            "LocationId": "NT_G0ZsvdP1AfF4LQmxtYsKjC_xUD",
                            "LocationType": "point",
                            "DisplayPosition": {
                                "Latitude": 50.11163,
                                "Longitude": 8.66109
                            },
                            "NavigationPosition": [
                                {
                                    "Latitude": 50.11168,
                                    "Longitude": 8.66128
                                }
                            ],
                            "MapView": {
                                "TopLeft": {
                                    "Latitude": 50.1127542,
                                    "Longitude": 8.6593371
                                },
                                "BottomRight": {
                                    "Latitude": 50.1105058,
                                    "Longitude": 8.6628429
                                }
                            },
                            "Address": {
                                "Label": "Savignystraße 15, 60325 Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland",
                                "Country": "DEU",
                                "State": "Hessen",
                                "County": "Frankfurt am Main",
                                "City": "Frankfurt am Main",
                                "District": "Westend",
                                "Street": "Savignystraße",
                                "HouseNumber": "15",
                                "PostalCode": "60325",
                                "AdditionalData": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "Deutschland",
                                        "key": "CountryName"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "Hessen",
                                        "key": "StateName"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "Frankfurt am Main",
                                        "key": "CountyName"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if data in response is an array or object. I'm considering that its an object as you pasted as response.

It should be like

```
res.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude
res.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem. Didint knew that View and Result are an Array that i have to access.